# Saving object with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables - Rasskazi (main table), CatsRelations (relations between table Rasskazi and table CatsNames) and CatsNames.

```
CREATE TABLE `rasskazi` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rasskazName` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rasskazText` text,
  `rasskazDataDobav` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rasskazRazmer` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `catsRelations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rasskazId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rasskazIdFK_idx` (`rasskazId`),
  KEY `catIdFK_idx` (`catId`),
  CONSTRAINT `z1` FOREIGN KEY (`rasskazId`) REFERENCES `rasskazi` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `z2` FOREIGN KEY (`catId`) REFERENCES `catsNames` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `catsNames` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catName` varchar(777) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `oldId_UNIQUE` (`oldId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Hibernate objects are:

```
Rasskazi.hbm.xml [http://pastebin.com/CF4D47M1][1]
Rasskazi.java [http://pastebin.com/29phnEEd][2]
CatsRelations.hbm.xml [http://pastebin.com/MqnXuAQ9][3]
CatsRelations.java [http://pastebin.com/BDqTKqeD][4]
CatsNames.hbm.xml [http://pastebin.com/9YtVkCjD][5]
CatsNames.java [http://pastebin.com/uwpWcLha][6]
```

All files packed to the zip and can be download [here](http://arturik.net/temp/dvddvddvd.zip)

I try to save objects by code

```
Rasskazi r = new Rasskazi();
    r.setRasskazName(storyName);
    Set<CatsRelations> catsRelationses = new HashSet<>();
    Elements katsInfo = doc.select("a[href*=ras.shtml?kat]");
    for (Element kat : katsInfo) {
        String katId = kat.attr("href");
        CatsNames cat = mainBean.getCat(katId); // Here I got CatsNames from my bean, from table named CatsNames

        CatsRelations catsRelations = new CatsRelations();
        catsRelations.setCatsNames(cat);
        catsRelations.setRasskazi(r);

        catsRelationses.add(catsRelations);

    }
    r.setCatsRelationses(catsRelationses);
    r.setRasskazText(textStr);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(r);
```

But Hibernate saves record only in table named rasskazi:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        grabberRasskazov.rasskazi
        (rasskazName, rasskazText, rasskazDataDobav, rasskazRazmer) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And it doesn't save any data to the table named CatsNames.
Why it doesn't save data to the table CatsNames, why it ignored the code

```
CatsRelations catsRelations = new CatsRelations();
catsRelations.setCatsNames(cat);
catsRelations.setRasskazi(r);

catsRelationses.add(catsRelations);

}
r.setCatsRelationses(catsRelationses);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't cascade from Parent to Children entities:

```
<set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="all">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
```

Make sure you add cascade to all one-to-many associations.